# PDF Overlay with Solid Colour

Tags: pdf, overlay, pdftk

I have a pdf with multiple pages (so doing the following manually is not an option).

Each page has text with a bright green strip bordering part of each page.

[image: What each page looks like...]

How can I replace it with a solid color (white preferred) so that it fits the rest of the page?

[image: Page without strip]

I tried searching

```
pdftk overlay white
```

but I'm still not sure how to create an alpha overlay (so that it will only cover the green part, but not the text).

Note: The green strip is at the same position for each page.

I also tried overlaying a white pdf page (created by exporting blank page as PDF from LibreOffice's menu) on top of the one with the strip, but the whole page turns white! (The original page is *below* the overlay)

How can I make the exported PDF completely transparent, except where I want it to be white?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out we need to turn an *image* (with alpha channel) into a PDF first.

```
convert image.png image.pdf
```

Then stamp `image.pdf` onto the original pdf

```
pdftk original.pdf stamp image.pdf output output.pdf
```